# Is it possible to track Active Cell change in Google Sheet Sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a sidebar which displays additional information based on selected row/cell by user. It's rendering fine on sidebar open, but if the user changes active cell, I need to update content.

Apparently, I can add a "refresh" button in sidebar, but I really want to avoid clicking "refresh" every time. Putting it on timer also isn't very good cause will just spam with unnecessary requests to sheet app.

Has anyone ever did something similar and that approach did you use?

Maybe it's possible somehow to get event about user changing active cell into the sidebar javascript code?

Comment: Polling........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've put together a prototype of a sidebar that collects all the cell the user clicks in.  Starting with an onSelectionChange() trigger to record the cells the user clicks in and recording them to PropertyService Document Properties, when the user moves the mouse over the sidebar the cells that were selected will show up.

First we have a simple Sidedbar

**HTML_Sidebar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="textArea" rows="10" cols="35" onmouseenter="onMouseEnter()">
    </textarea>
    <?!= include('JS_Sidebar'); ?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Next we have the client side code

**JS_Sidebar.html**

```
<script>
  function onMouseEnter() {
    try {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
        function(selections) {
          let textArea = document.getElementById("textArea");
          let text = textArea.value.trim();
          selections.forEach( cell => {
              text = text + "You clicked cell "+cell+"\n";
            }
          );
          textArea.value = text;
        }
      ).getLatestSelections();
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now for all the server side code.

**Code.gs**

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Sidebar");
  html = html.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function onSelectionChange(event) {
  try {
    // event = {"range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":3,"rowEnd":1,"rowStart":1},"authMode":"LIMITED","source":{},"user":
    //                  {"email":"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com","nickname":"xxxxxxxxx"}} 
    let properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    let property = properties.getProperty("_Selections");
    if( !property ) property = "";
    property = property + JSON.stringify(event) + "\n";
    properties.setProperty("_Selections",property);

  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in onSelectionChange: "+err)
  }
}

function getLatestSelections() {
  try {
    let properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    let property = properties.getProperty("_Selections");
    if( !property ) property = "";
    properties.deleteProperty("_Selections");
    properties = property.split("\n");
    properties.pop(); // remove the last  \n element
    return properties.map( property => {
        let cell = JSON.parse(property);
        return getRangeA1(cell.range.rowStart,cell.range.columnStart);
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in getLatestSelections: "+err)
  }
}

function getRangeA1(row,col) {
  try {
    let colNum = col;
    let colName = "";
    let modulo = 0;
    while( colNum > 0 ) {
      modulo = (colNum - 1) % 26;
      colName = String.fromCharCode(65 + modulo) + colName;
      colNum = Math.floor((colNum - modulo) / 26);
    }
    colName = colName+(row);
    return colName;
  }
  catch(err) {
    throw "Error in getRangeA1: "+err;
  }
}
```

**Screen shot**

[image]

Comment: I really love onSelectionChange  + onMouseEnter  combo. My case is much simpler than here(in a way), I just want to periodically refresh based on user activecell change, but it is much better than timer actually. Thanks! I didn't even knew about onSelectionChange trigger before.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to record when the active cells change on a Sheet, and you want to do it without resorting to timers or buttons. If my understanding of your scenario is correct, then your best bet is using [`onSelectionChange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) triggers.

You can introduce an `onSelectionChange` trigger in your script to execute a refresh every time that the user changes the active cell. Leave a comment below if you have questions about this approach.